# Automatically run a PHP script every X seconds without refreshing the page

Tags: php

I have a website, and in the navigation header, I have a player count, for the people who are currently online (On an external server). The count is outputted as a raw number generated by PlayersOnline.php, and I just include that.

How would I have this page update the player count every X seconds without refreshing the page?

Comment: Use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) from javascript to make a call to the php script, echo the values from the php script, and when Ajax returns to your javascript, update the counter using those echoed values.

Comment: You can use ajax with [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript and jQuery to solve this:

```
$(function() {
    updateCounter();
});

function updateCounter() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourScript.php',
        success: function(output) {
            $('#yourCounterElementID').text(output);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(updateCounter(), 5000);//run again in 5 seconds
        }
    });
}
```